# internet Explorer, Chrome gives Apache 500 server error, but not Firefox

Tags: apache, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a php page being called by a GET command from PayPal when the customer has paid for their holiday.  It works fine when the customer is using Firefox, returning a 200 in the Apache access log.  However if the customer is using IE (I'm testing using 10) the browser returns a HTTP 500 error page.  The access log has an identical line in it, but with a status of 500. The same happens with the customer using Chrome.

```
81.154.x.x - - [29/Jul/2013:12:14:10 +0100] "GET /customer/PayPalReturn.php?token=EC-0XY58825Nxxxxxxxx&PayerID=6Q9EJPLxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 200 4202
81.154.x.x - - [29/Jul/2013:12:32:51 +0100] "GET /customer/PayPalReturn.php?token=EC-0XY58825Nxxxxxxxx&PayerID=6Q9EJPLxxxxxx HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The Apache error log shows no errors.  Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: so that's the access log... what about the error log? that should include the PHP error message. Probably more useful in this case than the access log.

Comment: Also, just to confirm does your PHP code do any browser sniffing? ie any code specific to which browser is used?

Comment: The error log has no relevant php errors.  The problem is solved by checking all file ownership/permissions, and making sure that php sessions are being started correctly Still not sure why browsers differ though.